# Restricting MySQL 3306 port to localhost with IPTABLES

Tags: mysql, iptables

I am trying to restrict MySQL 3306 port on a linux machine from making any connections to anything other than localhost to prevent outside attacks. i have the following code, i am not sure if it's correct:

> ```
> iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s localhost --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT
>
> iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -s localhost --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT
>
> iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 3306 -j DROP
>
> iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 3306 -j DROP
> ```

my other question is - is it correct to only give localhost access? this is a standard dedicated centos webserver with more than 30 domains on it.

Comment: Why not just use the permissions when setting up the mysql user to only allow that user to log in from localhost   so it would be something like mysqluser@localhost instead of mysqluser@%

Comment: Forgive me asking but why don't you just use Unix sockets and `--skip-networking` if you don't want the port to be open?

Comment: Your iptable rules do work, I just tried them out.

Answer (score 17):

Why not just turn off networking with MySQL?

Add to my.cnf:

`skip-networking`

It's supposed to also give a negligible performance improvement by forcing connection through pipes, which skips over lots of tests used for the networking section. Please note you will need to use localhost, *not* 127.0.0.1, after the change.

Answer (score 9):

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 3306 -s 127.0.0.1 -d 127.0.0.1 -j ACCEPT
```

The above rule is for converting two lines into single one.

Answer to your second question:

If you do not want to provide mysql access from other than localhost, then it is perfect to configure this way. Simple. :-)

Comment: one would still need another rule to drop any connections that do not match the first rule, right?

Answer (score 5):

```bsh
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 3306 -s 127.0.0.1 -d 127.0.0.1 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 3306 -j DROP
```

If you want to remove the filtering, use this:

```bsh
iptables -D INPUT -p tcp --dport 3306 -s 127.0.0.1 -d 127.0.0.1 -j ACCEPT
iptables -D INPUT -p tcp --dport 3306 -j DROP
```

**Note**: Both might require root, so: `sudo iptables (...)`